# Why can't a variable be used in an XSL template selector predicate?

Tags: php, xslt-1.0

Given this XML;

```
<root>
  <foo x='1'/>
  <foo x='3'/>
  <foo x='7'/>
</root>
```

and this stylesheet;

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <result>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="foo"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo[@x > 2]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I get the desired result;

```
<result>
  <bar x="3"/>
  <bar x="7"/>
</result>
```

But if the template `match` for `foo` is changed to use a variable `$i` instead of a constant;

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="i" select="2"/>  

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <result>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="foo"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo[@x > $i]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

then I get this error;

```
XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: Failed to compile predicate
```

Am I doing something wrong or can't variables be used in that way?

I have tried declaring the variable in other ways eg;

```
  <xsl:variable name="i" select="2"/>
  <xsl:variable name="i">2<xsl:variable>
```

but it always fails to compile the stylesheet.

I'm using the PHP XSL 1.0 processor libxslt;

```
PHP Version      5.3.2
libxslt Version  1.1.23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, variables cannot be referred to in template match patterns (or in xsl:key instructions).

Why not?  Because the declaration of a variable is allowed to contain a call to xsl:apply-templates -- so allowing variable references in template match patterns would make circular variable declarations possible.